# Spring run method before starting endpoints

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to call some method while `Spring` is being initialized - after database connection is started but before `@RestController` endpoints are started (available to send requests)?

I need to send some database requests (using `JpaRepository`) before REST endpoints are ready.

I tried to find similiar post but I wasn't able to. I found annotation `@PostConstruct` or interfaces `CommandLineRunner` and  `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` but I think all of then are called after endpoints are started? Or am I wrong?

Comment: please, explain us what problem (what you need to do) you need to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@PostConstruct` is called after a bean is completely constructed but before it is "put into service"--which, in the case of a controller, means before it starts serving requests. (In the case of a service bean, this would mean before it is wired into any other beans.)

Note that it's best to use constructor injection to provide dependencies to your bean, but it may still be sensible to do database queries in `@PostConstruct` to avoid heavy operations in an actual constructor.

Comment: ok thanks, so as I understand I can use \@Autowired fields in method annotated with \@PostConstruct?

Comment: Yes, but it's best to avoid autowiring fields whenever possible, since it hides dependencies, makes testing hard, and can lead to obscure errors. Better to autowire the constructor if at all practical.